# MUI datagrid get selected row's cell content

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, datagrid

After selecting a row from the datagrid, I am trying to access each of the cell values of that row. However, I always get "undefined" when doing `selectedRowData.email`. What is the correct way of accessing a selected row's cell data?

```
<DataGrid
            checkboxSelection
            rows={adminData}
            columns={columns}
            getRowId={(row) => row._id}
            slots={{ toolbar: CustomToolbar }}
            onRowSelectionModelChange={(id) => {
              const selectedIDs = new Set(id);
              const selectedRowData = adminData.filter((row) =>
                selectedIDs.has(row._id)
              );

              console.log(selectedRowData); //prints object
              console.log(selectedRowData.email); //undefined }} />
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**selectedRowData** is an array.
You need to loop through it.

Replace this part of your code

```
        onRowSelectionModelChange={(id) => {
          const selectedIDs = new Set(id);
          const selectedRowData = adminData.filter((row) =>
            selectedIDs.has(row._id)
          );

          console.log(selectedRowData); //prints object
          console.log(selectedRowData.email); //undefined }} /
```

with

```
        onRowSelectionModelChange={(id) => {
            const selectedIDs = new Set(id);
            const selectedRowData = adminData.filter((row) =>
                selectedIDs.has(row._id)
            );
            selectedRowData.forEach((eachItem)=> {
                console.log(eachItem.email);
            });
          console.log(selectedRowData); //prints object
```